# jqueryui datepicker using closest call on html/body click not recognizing the dom outside of datepicker table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an example of the issue on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8a6mz/3/).

What I am trying to accomplish is when you click within the html/body of the document that I look to see if the event target element is within a div. This works fine until I introduce in the JQuery UI datepicker. When clicking within a day the anchor is not recognized to be within the outer div. It is like the only thing jQuery's closest call sees walking up through the tree stops at the table that the datepicker creates. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you meant stopPropagation.

Comment: Very strange.  If you traverse up through the parents of e.target it does in fact stop at the table.  But if you grab the table itself, it does have a parent...  http://jsfiddle.net/8a6mz/8/

Comment: Yeah that is what I found. It is like jqueryui is working in a different context for the event target. This is specific to the control as well. I tried it with a simple table structure and It was able to traverse the dom correctly.

Comment: I did mean stopPropagation. I must of forgot to update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `datepickerEl` as a **global** variable, as it doesn't reach *click* handler scope.

Another change i would make is to change *if* condition method `closest` to `parents`, as elements inside datepicker can be clicked and are still inside `class="outer"` div

Also, you need to change event call to `e.stopPropagation()` (you confused method name with `e.preventDefault()`, i guess only used for *click*, *submit*, etc. events default behavior).

I supose this is what you are searching:

```
var datepickerEl;
$(function() {
    datepickerEl = $('.outer').datepicker();
    $('html,body').click(function(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
         if ( ! $(e.target).parents([datepickerEl]).length ) {
             alert('What is going on');
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: It does seem that using parents is working where outer is not. I thought that outer would traverse up the chain until it found a matching element or until it can't traverse anymore and parents continues even after it finds the match to see if any others match.

Comment: So it doesn't need the global option but it does seem that parents() will actually traverse up the chain correctly. Unsure why because I thought the only difference was one stops after a match and the other one finds all matches. [(The example on jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8a6mz/10/) What is weird is if you switch out parents with closest it doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, It doesn't seem to work. The parents call is returning a length of 4 which seems wrong. [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/8a6mz/11/) Still unsure why this is not working.

Comment: sorry, i think i didn't understand very well your question then :S... alert() should popup when you click on a div or inside it, but not outside? only outside elements closest to the target div? thx